# Java: JFileChooser How to show Selected File in a textField

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a JFileChooser and Im able to print the Absolute Path in console.
I need to show the FilePath in a Text field as soon as the User selects the file.

Below is the code please let me know how to do it.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int showOpenDialog = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

        if (showOpenDialog != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
```

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: If you know how to get the absolute path of the selected file why don't you just put it into the textfield?

Comment: *"Please let me know if you need any other details."*  How about: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for ur reply, I tried putting in a Text Field but nothing happened to the Text Field.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i tried a JfileChooser to Upload a File to AWS s3 server, and im able to upload the file but i need to show the path of the file which is uploading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen to the changes that occur when using the JFileChooser, see this snipet of code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

// Add listener on chooser to detect changes to selected file
chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY
                .equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            JFileChooser chooser = (JFileChooser)evt.getSource();
            File oldFile = (File)evt.getOldValue();
            File newFile = (File)evt.getNewValue();

            // The selected file should always be the same as newFile
            File curFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        } else if (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILES_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(
                evt.getPropertyName())) {
            JFileChooser chooser = (JFileChooser)evt.getSource();
            File[] oldFiles = (File[])evt.getOldValue();
            File[] newFiles = (File[])evt.getNewValue();

            // Get list of selected files
            // The selected files should always be the same as newFiles
            File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        }
    }
}) ;
```

All you need to do inside the first condition is set the value of your textfield to match the new selected filename. See this example:

```
yourTextfield.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
```

Or just

```
yourTextfield.setText(curFile.getName());
```

It is the method getName() from class File that will give you what you need.
Help your self from de [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to see what each method does.

Comment: Showing just the name is a poor idea, especially when the OP explicitly states *"I need to show the **FilePath** in a Text field"*.  Please adjust your post to save me the bother of down-voting.

Comment: @Andrew, Im not well versed in English or communication. However I can improve myself in my future posting.

Comment: @sfrj: My client asked me to change the TextField to JLabel, and i have done that.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I am sure he will find the method to show the path in the API documentation(i think it is getPath() or getCannonicalPath()) i think that is not a big deal. I dont see that a reason for down voting. 1- I suggested to read the documentation and 2- I gave an example not a solution.

Comment: @Ananthavel Sundararajan Dont worry JTextField and JLabel, are pretty similar in their methods, im almost sure it will work even if you do that for an object of type JLabel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to show the path in a text field.

```
if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    textField.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using what Genhis has said, please see the full code block you can use to get a 'browse' button to place the file path in a correlating JTextField.

```
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Browse");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("File Browser.");
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(btnNewButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                textField.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    });
```